# Phalcon PHP has-many relation between a SQL and noSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, has-many, phalcon

I am wondering if it is possible to have a has-many relation between a table in MySQL and a collection in MongoDB with Phalcon.

Comment: Dunno. What has your research turned up?

Comment: Does Phalcon have its own ORM? My guess would be that you could write a method in the MySQL table class to emulate such a relation (but, for the avoidance of doubt, it would not do a join of any kind at the MySQL/noSQL level).

Comment: it has the ORM and the ODM as well, Sure it can be achieved manually by implementing some logic but then you won't be able to benefit it's database relational methods

Comment: I don't know Phalcon, but presumably the relational methods of its ORM will translate at some point into SQL JOINs. Since NoSQL doesn't have relational JOINs, it is unlikely to support it. Still, let's not guess: this is something that needs to be thoroughly researched.

Comment: I cannot tell if it uses only SQL Joins or not because the core is C compiled but I would keep hoping there's a way around because Phalcon is so huge and full-featured otherwise I'll try if i can achieve it with a custom dependency injection or something and self-answer my thread if there's any success

Comment: "the core is C compiled" - I expect that is open source though?

Comment: Ok, let's remove the word 'compiled' from my sentence and say I'm not a very C kind of guy (yet at least), i could track the usage of SQL Joins on the source but yet couldn't track any other approaches than Join for that, if you're interested you can take a look at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phalcon/cphalcon/master/build/32bits/phalcon.c  hasMany & addhasmany